# Select some items and if there's not enough of them, add some other items, then sort

Tags: mysql

Here's my table `items`:

```
id    type        important    date                
--------------------------------------------------
1     articles    0            2013-11-14 01:10:00
2     articles    0            2013-11-14 02:45:00
3     articles    1            2013-11-15 03:00:00
4     articles    0            2013-11-15 04:23:00
5     articles    1            2013-11-17 05:21:00
6     news        0            2013-11-18 06:00:00
7     news        0            2013-11-19 07:00:00
8     news        0            2013-11-19 08:00:00
```

I need to display three important items or, if there's not enough of them, add news to the mix till there are three. And then sort them by date from newest to oldest.

If I write this simply as:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE important = 1 OR type = 'news' 
ORDER BY `important` DESC, `date` DESC LIMIT 3
```

then two important items will be higher than the newest news item. But I need to get this:

```
id    type        important    date                
--------------------------------------------------
8     news        0            2013-11-19 08:00:00
5     articles    1            2013-11-17 05:21:00
3     articles    1            2013-11-15 03:00:00
```

How can I do this with SQL?

Comment: Do you just want the reverse order? Change DESC to ASC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this do the trick?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE important = 1 OR type = 'news' 
    ORDER BY `important` DESC, `date` DESC LIMIT 3
) x
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, dead simple. How could I forget that! I probably need to take a break :)